# error coming when i try to take input for 10 numbers with a variable in the input placeholder text

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello so my main objective is to ask user for 10 numbers and then show them the sum of those 10 numbers provided by user

```
sum=0
for i in range(1,11):
    num=int(input("enter number",i," :"))
    sum=sum+num
print("The sum of given 10 numbers is :",sum)
```

this is my code but its giving me error in Line 3
saying
 `num=int(input("enter number",i," :")) TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 3`

what I did was to make a variable sum and initialize it to 0 then make a for loop

```
for i in range(1,11):
```

that will run exactly 10 times and then inside that for loop I asked users for input so that will ask to input numbers 10 times now under this input display text
for eg :

```
num=int(input('Enter Number 1 :"))
```

instead of number `1` I wanted to make it dynamic so `i` put i instead of it

```
num=int(input("Enter number ",i," :"))
```

to make it ask new number every loop
like
enter number 1 in first loop then enter number 2 in second loop and till 10th loop.
but it gave me error I mentioned above.

please help me where i made mistake and what i did wrong.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python input() method only takes 1 argument and you are providing 3!
So to chain these arguments together simply use thy + operator instead of ,
So it should look like:

```
num=int(input("Enter number " + str(i) + " :"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The *input()* function takes one parameter (as indicated in the error message). You could build the prompt using an f-string as follows:

```
num=int(input(f'Enter number {i}:'))
```

Comment: Thank You for showing me the explanation and the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one of several string formatting:

```
num = int(input('enter number {}:'.format(i)))
```

or

```
num = int(input('enter number %s:' % i))
```

And also don't use `sum` as variable names. `sum` is built-in function